# Error accessing my webpage from network

Tags: python, flask, hosting, web-hosting, host

I've just started learning network developing using **Flask**. According to its official tutorial:

> **Externally Visible Server**
>
> If you run the server you will notice that the server is only
>   accessible from your own computer, not from any other in the network.
>   This is the default because in debugging mode a user of the
>   application can execute arbitrary Python code on your computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
>   you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
>   `--host=0.0.0.0` to the command line:
>
> ```
> flask run --host=0.0.0.0
> ```
>
> This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

However, when I try to access `0.0.0.0:5000` on another device, I got an error: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE`. In fact, I think this behavior is reasonable, since people all around world can use `0.0.0.0:5000` for different testing purposes, but isn't the tutorial implying that adding `--host=0.0.0.0` can make my webpage "accessible not only from your own computer, but also from any other in the network"?

So, my question is:

1. What does adding `--host=0.0.0.0` do?
2. How can I access my webpage on device B while the server is running on device A?

Comment: I flagged this question as off-topic because it belongs on superuser. Anyway, `--host=0.0.0.0` only means that the server will listen for connections from all IP addresses, not that you should use `http://0.0.0.0:5000` to access it. You should use your external IP address, and make sure that it is forwarded in your router if you are behind NAT (or if you are within the local network you should use the hosting PC's local IP address). Any more than that is **really** out of scope for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't access the Flask server on another computer by going to `0.0.0.0:5000`. Instead, you need to put in the IP address of the computer that it is running on.

For example, if you are developing on a computer that has IP address `10.10.0.1`, you can run the server like so:

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
```

This will start the server (on `10.10.0.1:5000`) and listen for any connections from anywhere. Now your other device (say, on `10.10.0.2`) can access that server by going to `http://10.10.0.1:5000` in the browser.

If you don't have the `host=0.0.0.0`, the server on `10.10.0.1` will only listen for connections from *itself* (localhost). By adding that parameter, you are telling it to listen from connections external to itself.

Comment: Thank you for answering my probably off-topic question, but the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE` error remains. The command I used to retrieve my external IP address is `curl -s http://whatismijnip.nl |cut -d " " -f 5
`.

Comment: You don't have a port specified in that `curl` command. Does `http://whatismijnip.nl:5000` work? Also, do you have a firewall on the host device that is preventing connections?

Comment: Firewall is turned off, and `http://whatismijnip.nl:5000` works on neither device A nor device B :( Maybe I just failed to get the correct external IP address?

Comment: Possible. Depending on your network set up, you may need to forward traffic to the device too. You can do this in your router set up

Comment: I have another question: Is `--port` default to `5000`? I've run `flask run --help`, but the output didn't tell me anything about the "default value".

Comment: [Yes](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.run): `port – the port of the webserver. Defaults to 5000 or the port defined in the SERVER_NAME config variable if present.`